# JS function for smooth page load - order issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Pretty difficult to explain so please bear with me.

I have a page that opens with a heading and paragraph tag, I then have a number of images following that.

My images are my portfolio and when clicked I'm going to use AJAX to populate the page on the fly.

When a user clicks the title on the image, I want the following actions to occur...

- Window scrolls to top of that image
- Borders are all removed (See JSFiddle link)
- Using AJAX I can then populate the page underneath the new image

The issue I'm having is that I need to remove the content above my image so when the window scrolls to the selected portfolio piece and the content is then removed it becomes unstable and jittery.

Here's a link...

https://jsfiddle.net/oterdwn1/

and here's my current JS...

**JS**

```
$('a.video').on('click', function(e) {

  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.hero-pane').css('overflow') == 'hidden') {
    return false;
  }

  var dstn = $(this).attr('href');
  var className = $(this).data('class');


  var tgt = $(this);


  $('.studies a').each(function() {
    $('.hero-pane').css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    if ($(this).data("class") !== className) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  })
  $('.hero-pane').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('.hero-pane').css('min-height', '0px');
  $('.hero-pane').css('max-height', '1000px');


  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: (tgt).offset().top
    },
    800,
    function() {

      $(tgt).find($('.border-left, .border-right')).css('width', 0);
      $(tgt).find($('.border-top, .border-bottom')).css('height', 0);

      $('.hero-pane').delay(200).animate({
        'max-height': '0px'
      }, 100);
      $('.hero-pane').delay(200).animate({
        'padding-top': '0px'
      }, 100);
      $('.hero-pane').delay(200).animate({
        'padding-bottom': '0px'
      }, 100);
      $('.studies').delay(1000).animate({
        'margin-top': '-100px'
      }, 400);
      $('html,body').delay(1000).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 400, function() {
        //$('html, body').css({
        //   overflow: 'visible',
        //   height: 'auto'
        //});
      });


    });


  $('#' + className + '-study-title').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    getPageHTML(dstn, className);
  });


});
```

Comment: Are you sure about this: `$('#' + className` ?

Comment: So you want to remove the content above your image and make image's animation stable and not jittery, right? If not, please describe what you want.

Comment: You might want to consider using velocity.js and the velocity.runSequence - I found it improved animation smoothness compared to raw jquery animation for complex sequences

Comment: Hi @blackmiaool, Yes I want to remove all the content above my picture. The issue im having is if i `scrollTo` my image and then remove the content above the image then jumps up. If i remove it first I get a big white area so im at a loss as to how to write it - make sense?

Comment: @Liam Seems you just want a way to make the pic fill the screen, right?  If so, there's no need to remove the above content.

Comment: @blackmiaool I then pull in the content to form my new page beneath that image - essentially the image forms the new header so I can't have content above it showing.

Comment: why you don't use `position: fixed;` for clicked image?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you **can't** **animate** your **max-height** style. Try to use "slideUp".

```js
$('a.video').on('click', function(e) {

  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.hero-pane').css('overflow') == 'hidden') {
    return false;
  }

  var dstn = $(this).attr('href');
  var className = $(this).data('class');


  var tgt = $(this);


  $('.studies a').each(function() {
    $('.hero-pane').css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    if ($(this).data("class") !== className) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  })
  $('.hero-pane').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('.hero-pane').css('min-height', '0px');
  $('.hero-pane').css('max-height', '1000px');


  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: (tgt).offset().top
    },
    800,
    function() {
      $(tgt).find($('.border-left, .border-right')).css('width', 0);
      $(tgt).find($('.border-top, .border-bottom')).css('height', 0);
      $('.hero-pane').slideUp(1000)
      $('.hero-pane').delay(200).animate({
      //  'max-height': '0px',
        'padding-top': '0px',
        'padding-bottom': '0px'
      }, 100);
      return;
      $('.studies').delay(1000).animate({
        'margin-top': '-100px'
      }, 400);
      $('html,body').delay(1000).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 400, function() {});

    });

  $('#' + className + '-study-title').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    getPageHTML(dstn, className);
  });


});
```

```css
.studies {
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 650px;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
}

.video img {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.border-top,
.border-bottom,
.border-top:after,
.border-bottom:after,
.border-left,
.border-right,
.border-left:after,
.border-right:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.border-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}

.border-top,
.border-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0;
}

.border-left,
.border-right {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 65px;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: 0;
}

.border-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.border-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}

.brand-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  bottom: 7.5%;
  left: 7.5%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-pane">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="studies">

    <a href="#" data-class="brand1" class="video brand1" style="z-index: 2">
      <div class="border-top"></div>
      <div class="border-bottom"></div>
      <div class="border-left"></div>
      <div class="border-right"></div>
      <div id="brand-study-title" class="brand-title">
        <div class="faux-link">
          <h4>Title</h4>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
    </a>

    <a href="#" data-class="brand2" class="video brand2" style="z-index: 2">
      <div class="border-top"></div>
      <div class="border-bottom"></div>
      <div class="border-left"></div>
      <div class="border-right"></div>
      <div id="brand-2-study-title" class="brand-title">
        <div class="faux-link">
          <h4>Title 2</h4>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```